# Non uniqueness of derivative at an accumulation point?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

In the excelent book "Advanced calculus" by Hans Sagans there is the following excerpt:

[image]

In chapter 3 he defined the derivative of a function at an accumulation point of its domain. Next, in the context of several variables, he says that if we tried to define the derivative of a function at an accumulation point of its domain we would not have the uniqueness of the derivative.

Can anyone give me an example where the uniqueness would fail?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps a bit imprecisely, you could think of the derivative of $f(x,y)$ at $(a,b)$ as the tangent plane to the graph of $f$ at the point $(a,b,f(a,b))$. Say $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ but your $D$ is the $x$-axis. Then any plane that contains the $x$-axis would be a "tangent" plane to the graph of the restriction of $f$ to the $x$-axis. The latter graph is just a parabola $f(x,y)=x^2$ in the $xz$-coordinate plane, and both the $xy$-coordinate plane and the $xz$-coordinate plane are tangent to this graph, as is any plane through the origin $(0,0)$ containing the $x$-axis.

Comment: What is ${\cal D}$? If you consider ${\cal D} = \{ (x,0) \}$ and $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ then any of $g\cdot h = 2h_1 + \alpha h_2$ satisfy the required equation for the derivative. Since $\alpha$ is arbitrary, it is not uniquely defined.